# Using subqueries to obtain sorted data

Tags: sql, subquery

So for a school assignment, I need to output the student last name and first name, and just the first 8 that have enrolled, sorted as such. I'm not going to worry about the limiting it to 8 (that's easy when everything else works), but I need to figure out what I'm doing wrong and need to do here. Here's what I have:

```
SELECT student.first_name, student.last_name
FROM student 
WHERE student.student_id IN (SELECT  enrollment.student_id
FROM enrollment
ORDER BY enrollment.enroll_date);
```

Comment: Please explain also what is wrong with this query, for example what is the result and how it differs from what you expect to get

Comment: Oh right: I'm getting error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 1
But I'm not missing the parentheses so I'm not sure exactly what it's complaining about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well because oracle actually see your code like this:

```
SELECT student.first_name, student.last_name
FROM student 
WHERE student.student_id IN (
SELECT enrollment.student_id FROM 
enrollment ) --where the ) should be!!!
ORDER BY enrollment.enroll_date  --and this line just mess up the code delete this.
```

the reason why this happen is in the subquery you try to `order by`. Just get rid of that `order by` or use it outside the subquery and the error should not occur anymore.

Beside when you use `IN` there is no meaning to use `order by` in that subquery.